# getting error while creating new project in android studio

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio

I've successfully used android studio when it was first released.

But after Update it started giving me errors for gradle
earlier I was getting "Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+." error

I googled too much but the solution I found was to replace .gradle directory in C:/doc&settng/[username]/.gradle 
and/or update in c:/doc&settng/[username]/.androidstudiopreview
But I could find .androidstudiopreview directory.

today i got notification for new patch available
after applying patch, the error changed to this.

Failed to import Gradle project: Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.5.6/gradle-0.5.6.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden: APP signature match

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Can anyone help me to get rid of this error?

I've android sdk tools 22.0.5 installed
android support repository, and android support library installed.

Comment: Are you using Gradle Wrapper ? If not, you should use it : http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html